# Windows 8.1 High memory usage (Unknown source)

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, drivers, memory-leaks

For awhile now my laptop has been running incredibly slow and I'm suspecting it's from the unexplained high memory usage I've been seeing for a few weeks now. I've looked into a number of things, but haven't been able to figure out what exactly is causing it. I was hoping someone on here might have some insight into the problem. I've attached pictures of Ram Map, Task Manager, WPA, Poolmon log, and a tasklist to hopefully help.

When it first boots up it seems to be okay but at some random point in time later the ram usage just shoots up.

Ram Map:

[image]

Task Manager:

[image]

WPA ResidentSet:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/jyy4t.png]

Poolmon Log:

[image]

**TaskList**

`Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0          4 K
System                           4 Services                   0        932 K
smss.exe                       340 Services                   0         28 K
csrss.exe                      516 Services                   0      1,944 K
wininit.exe                    604 Services                   0         32 K
services.exe                   652 Services                   0      5,068 K
lsass.exe                      660 Services                   0      7,652 K
svchost.exe                    736 Services                   0      6,728 K
svchost.exe                    768 Services                   0      8,376 K
ASCService.exe                 904 Services                   0      4,344 K
nvvsvc.exe                     320 Services                   0         40 K
nvSCPAPISvr.exe                396 Services                   0      1,468 K
svchost.exe                    520 Services                   0     17,056 K
svchost.exe                    600 Services                   0     28,768 K
svchost.exe                    880 Services                   0     32,752 K
svchost.exe                   1076 Services                   0      8,812 K
svchost.exe                   1284 Services                   0     10,812 K
spoolsv.exe                   1488 Services                   0      5,552 K
svchost.exe                   1528 Services                   0     15,672 K
svchost.exe                   1780 Services                   0      7,476 K
ETDService.exe                1804 Services                   0         28 K
GfExperienceService.exe       1840 Services                   0        196 K
ibtrksrv.exe                  1904 Services                   0         40 K
IpOverUsbSvc.exe              1936 Services                   0      1,604 K
LiveUpdate.exe                2008 Services                   0        920 K
NvNetworkService.exe          1640 Services                   0         64 K
NvStreamService.exe           1300 Services                   0        688 K
sqlwriter.exe                 2080 Services                   0        816 K
MsMpEng.exe                   2112 Services                   0      1,288 K
svchost.exe                   2636 Services                   0      2,728 K
svchost.exe                   2684 Services                   0      4,552 K
WUDFHost.exe                  1352 Services                   0         80 K
NvStreamNetworkService.ex     3176 Services                   0      1,168 K
svchost.exe                   3160 Services                   0      2,904 K
dllhost.exe                   4092 Services                   0      1,532 K
GoogleCrashHandler.exe        5428 Services                   0      1,008 K
GoogleCrashHandler64.exe      5436 Services                   0         48 K
devmonsrv.exe                 2092 Services                   0      2,320 K
obexsrv.exe                    420 Services                   0        440 K
svchost.exe                 173256 Services                   0        696 K
audiodg.exe                 659408 Services                   0      6,820 K
dasHost.exe                 591264 Services                   0      5,936 K
csrss.exe                   732396 Console                    4      3,764 K
winlogon.exe                731168 Console                    4      1,360 K
dwm.exe                     731340 Console                    4     19,024 K
nvxdsync.exe                678980 Console                    4        892 K
nvvsvc.exe                  730272 Console                    4        336 K
ETDCtrl.exe                 617684 Console                    4        992 K
taskhostex.exe              681892 Console                    4      5,580 K
Monitor.exe                 592424 Console                    4      3,700 K
explorer.exe                733136 Console                    4     56,476 K
ETDCtrlHelper.exe           593144 Console                    4        652 K
ETDIntelligent.exe          601304 Console                    4        888 K
nvtray.exe                  733576 Console                    4        240 K
NvBackend.exe               601912 Console                    4      6,844 K
puush.exe                   730032 Console                    4      1,432 K
flux.exe                    541552 Console                    4      2,604 K
GWX.exe                     588040 Console                    4        184 K
netsession_win.exe          730812 Console                    4        548 K
netsession_win.exe          729484 Console                    4      3,452 K
ASCTray.exe                 587200 Console                    4      3,624 K
SheeplessHelper.exe         295020 Console                    4      3,248 K
Spotify.exe                 432844 Console                    4     27,624 K
TSVNCache.exe               681452 Console                    4      2,448 K
SpotifyCrashService.exe     565788 Console                    4        448 K
Spotify.exe                 291152 Console                    4     20,404 K
SpotifyWebHelper.exe        519648 Console                    4        448 K
Spotify.exe                 293956 Console                    4     60,824 K
NvStreamUserAgent.exe       602268 Console                    4        920 K
conhost.exe                 730372 Console                    4        344 K
UninstallMonitor.exe        733424 Console                    4      5,432 K
SettingSyncHost.exe           3776 Console                    4         76 K
chrome.exe                  730276 Console                    4    112,320 K
chrome.exe                  732412 Console                    4        740 K
chrome.exe                  732680 Console                    4     38,696 K
chrome.exe                  682116 Console                    4      8,528 K
chrome.exe                  682644 Console                    4     57,576 K
chrome.exe                  733180 Console                    4     20,400 K
chrome.exe                  732484 Console                    4     13,716 K
chrome.exe                  591796 Console                    4     28,136 K
explorer.exe                585400 Console                    4     57,020 K
chrome.exe                    3276 Console                    4     43,532 K
cmd.exe                       3256 Console                    4      7,056 K
conhost.exe                 680676 Console                    4      1,984 K
chrome.exe                  732260 Console                    4     20,440 K
taskhost.exe                734616 Console                    4      6,100 K
chrome.exe                  735676 Console                    4     34,060 K
mbam.exe                    735640 Console                    4     18,212 K
chrome.exe                  682144 Console                    4     34,180 K
chrome.exe                  584956 Console                    4     70,400 K
chrome.exe                  734548 Console                    4     46,360 K
chrome.exe                  731876 Console                    4     64,784 K
cmd.exe                     735140 Console                    4      2,668 K
conhost.exe                 731524 Console                    4      7,440 K
sublime_text.exe            733012 Console                    4     23,004 K
plugin_host.exe             733928 Console                    4     30,428 K
chrome.exe                  602548 Console                    4     64,380 K
chrome.exe                  635408 Console                    4     78,664 K
Taskmgr.exe                 601928 Console                    4     25,536 K
chrome.exe                  733096 Console                    4     43,288 K
chrome.exe                  735504 Console                    4     40,136 K
tasklist.exe                735292 Console                    4      5,628 K
WmiPrvSE.exe                736128 Services                   0      5,880 K`

Comment: Your Page Table memory is insane. Have you taken a look at http://superuser.com/questions/782855/why-does-my-page-table-take-up-so-much-memory ?

Comment: Yes and I run into the same issue of the Page Table being used by "Unknown (-1)". I'm going to be watching it closely over the next few days since it just occurred to me that it could have something to do with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: unknown (-1) is hard to debug. Use clean boot approach to detect 3rd party application that cause it. Lenovo "RapidBoot Shield" is known to cause it

Comment: were you able to isolate which tool caused it?

Comment: Nope still haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: do you use a Lenovo laptop? If yes, do you have this "RapidBoot Shield" software installed?