# 90% Memory Usage On Windows 10

Tags: memory, windows-10

I noticed today that I had extremely high memory usage on windows 10 and couldn't find any process that uses a lot of memory.

Here is a screenshot of my memory usage:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of poolmon.exe

[image]

Can someone please tell me what is causing such high memory usage? Thanks!

Comment: Windows 10 is correct about the total memory used, but the processes/details page is almost always completely wrong. Generally, programs use a lot more then reported by windows, so closing some open programs free up some memory. To point out exactly whats taking so much memory, please take a screenshot of the "Details" tab after pressing the "Memory" once. This orders all the processes by memory use.

Comment: As I said it provides no useful information at all, hence why I posted the poolmon screenshot.

Comment: Can I see what this useless information is please?

Comment: the PRC, TOKE tags are too high. You need to run a xperf trace of the memory usage **GROW** after installing the WPT, which is part of the Windwos 10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk: **xperf -on BASE+Pool+ReferenceSet -stackwalk PoolAlloc+PoolFree -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 2048 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\trace_pool_alloc.etl**. Capture 1-2 minutes of te grow, zip the ETL file (to dramatically reduce the file size), upload the zip to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here.

Comment: Just ran that since the issues happened again today. I uploaded it to my personal Dropbox. Direct link here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91292881/ShareX/2015/12/kernel.zip

Comment: were you able to find which process caused the high page table usage by disabling 3rd party tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, there are several pool tags that are too high.

The `PROC` usage comes from `wscsvc.dll!SetDefenderStatus` calls from the security center service in Windows.

The `toke` usage `MpCmdRun.exe` (Microsoft Malware Protection Command Line Utility), which is also Windows Defender.

The `io` tag usage comes from the tool Agent.exe which calls the driver EuPipe.dll. Those files are part of `EaseUS Todo Backup` (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\EaseUS\Todo Backup\bin\Agent.exe"`)

the `SeTd` tag is also used by MpCmdRun.exe.

1 large part of the memory usage is the [PageTable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table). But I can't see which process caused it. We had [such issues already here](https://superuser.com/a/769002/174557) and some 3rd party tool caused it. Disable all 3rd party tools/drivers until you found the program that causes the high page table usage.